# How to get detailed error messages from Java Kafka AdminClient when creating topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I need to create some Kafka topics from a Java program.

I am using the `AdminClient` class method `createTopics` to which I pass an array of `NewTopic`.

Let's say I want to create 3 topics: **T1**, **T2** and **T3**. Let's say that **T1** and **T2** already exist, while **T3** doesn't.

My code is

```
NewTopic t1 = new NewTopic("T1", 3, (short)3);
NewTopic t2 = new NewTopic("T2", 3, (short)3);
NewTopic t2 = new NewTopic("T3", 3, (short)3);

List<NewTopic> newTopics = new ArrayList<NewTopic>();
newTopics.add("T1");
newTopics.add("T2");
newTopics.add("T3");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaConnectString);
try (final AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(properties)) {
   final CreateTopicsResult createTopicsResult = adminClient.createTopics(newTopics);
   createTopicsResult.all().get();
} catch (Exception e) {
   logger.info(e.toString());
}
```

The result I get is the following:

- on the console a message that **T1** already exists and no mention of
  **T2**
- in Kafka **T1**, **T2** and **T3** present, meaning that **T3** was
  actually created

Is there a possibility to get a message that says that also **T2** was not created because already existing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently(Kafka 2.3), it is impossible for Kafka to display a single message explicitly indicating all the existing topics. However, you could try coding like this to get multiple error messages:

```
 ......
 CreateTopicsResult result = client.createTopics(Arrays.asList(t1, t2, t3));
 result.values().values().stream().forEach(f -> {
        try {
            f.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
 });
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks, this work. I actually made a small variation to your code so that I can have programmatic access to the name of the Topic which fails. My coded looks like `createTopicsResult.values().forEach((k, f) -> {
                    try {
                        f.get();
                    } catch (Exception e) { // do stuff to manage the exception, where k contains the name of the Topic which failed }}`